# Simple example of Masstransit using one Queue with amazon SQS

Tags: amazon-sqs, masstransit

I am facing a problem with masstransit. I want to use SQS and one queue only. I want masstransit to always send the messages to that queue and receive them on a specific endpoint. (So not publishing). 
The sending to the queue works but for some reason I'm having problems receiving messages. The documentation examples do not work for me when connecting a consumer to an endpoint.. It complains about SNS (which I am not using)

Does anyone have a simple example?

[image: The setup of the bus for the send to the queue (this works)]

[image: The setup of the receiving end as described by the documentation. (Does not work)]

[image: the TestConsumer]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11102471

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I found out that if you want to send messages to a queue, than SQS should be sufficient in combination with Masstransit. But when you want to recieve those messages, then Masstransit expects credentials that allow the creation of SNS topics.

I thought I had more say in what queues Masstransit will use for communication. But when you use Masstransit with amazon it will create it's own queues and SNS topics based on it's needs.

So when using Masstransit, like i did in my case. Give it AWS IAM user credentials that have the proper permissions to create SQS queues and SNS topics.

Comment: If you configure the receive endpoint to not bind topics to queues, it won't create anything in SNS.